# Why my simple chat in nodejs using websockets won't send messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket

The chat is programmed in nodejs using websockets from socket.io library and i have a client that also uses websockets from socket.io but I don't manage to make the two work together. For some reason the client doesn't send the message to the server (I have a console.log function that should write to console when it receives a message but it doesn't write anything).

The code for the server is:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
       console.log('message: ' + msg);
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

And for the client is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        * { margin:0; padding:0; font-size:11px; font-family:arial; color:#444; }
        body { padding:20px; }
        #message-list { list-style-type:none; width:300px; height:300px; overflow:auto; border:1px solid #999; padding:20px; }
        #message-list li { border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; padding-bottom:2px; margin-bottom:5px; }
        code { font-family:courier; background:#eee; padding:2px 4px; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://cdn.socket.io/stable/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>



        // Sends a message to the server via sockets
        function sendMessageToServer(message) {
            socket.send(message);
            log('<span style="color:#888">Sending "' + message + '" to the server!</span>');
        }

        // Outputs to console and list
        function log(message) {
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.innerHTML = message;
            document.getElementById('message-list').appendChild(li);
        }


        // Create a socket instance
        socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

        // Open the socket
        socket.onopen = function(event) {
            console.log('Socket opened on client side',event);

            // Listen for messages
            socket.onmessage = function(event) {
                console.log('Client received a message',event);
            };

            // Listen for socket closes
            socket.onclose = function(event) {
                console.log('Client notified socket has closed',event);
            };

        };


    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Messages will appear below (and in the console).</p><br />
    <ul id="message-list"></ul>
    <ul style="margin:20px 0 0 20px;">
        <li>Type <code>socket.disconnect()</code> to disconnect</li>
        <li>Type <code>socket.connect()</code> to reconnect</li>
        <li>Type <code>sendMessageToServer('Your Message')</code> to send a message to the server</li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong here? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try changing from `socket.on('chat message'` to `socket.on('message'`, please.. As per [docs](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-send-args-ack): `socket.send` _Sends a `message` event._, so you need to listen for the correct one in the server.

Comment: Besides, that cdn is broken... Maybe you are just following an outdated tutorial, please refere to: [https://socket.io/get-started/chat/](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/)

Comment: I changed 'chat message' to 'message' but is still the same problem

Comment: https://socket.io/get-started/chat/ : that is the exact tutorial i followed and there it uses 'chat message' instead of 'message'

Comment: First, the tutorial uses jquery (but i'm reasonable, it's ok if you change that). Second, they use `socket.emit`, not `socket.send`.. and again, if you hit F12, in the console you'll see that the cdn you're trying to get socket.io from is dead. oh well

Comment: Thanks! I looked closer and there are some differences. Good luck yourself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple issues based on my knowledge. If they are all fixed, it should work.

1. The connection socket.io.js file should be your own one. In your case, I am guessing it is `<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket/socket.io.js"></script>` I am not 100 percent sure because your port could vary.
2. You didn't define socket properly on your client side. Define it as this: `var socket = io();`. The way you did it is `socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');` Where WebSocket is not defined. And, the code will create a new websocket server, which you already did in your server code. What you need to do at client side is only connect to the server.
3. You must use the same channel to let the client and server to communicate. So in your client code, you should send message like this `socket.emit('chat message', 'content you want to send'`.
4. I don't know why you emit the message at server side again BTW. I am assuming you are sending message from client to server. So you shouldn't have emit command in your server code.

If all the four things been fixed, it will work.

In case my expression is not clear, I wrote a super simple example for you:

Server side:

```
let io = socketio(server.listener);
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log("A user connected");

    // auto messages when a user is connected
    setTimeout(function() {
        socket.send("message at 4 seconds");
    }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        socket.send("message at 8 seconds");
    }, 8000);

    // callback when a user disconnected
    socket.on("disconnect", function(){
        console.log("A user disconnected");
    });

    // receive message from client
    socket.on("client-server", function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    });
});

// you put this code anywhere when you need to send message from server to client
io.emit("server-client", "server to client message");
```

Client side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>Hello world</title></head>
  <script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('server-client', function(data) {document.write(data)});
    socket.emit('client-server', 'test message');
  </script>
  <body>Hello world</body>
</html>
```

My server code is written in typescript so never mind the let key word, double quote and so on.